# Make things appear when visible on screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I know this may be asked a bunch of time but i'm beginner with jQuery and I'd like to understand what I do.

I used [Multi-screen.js](http://www.ian-devries.com/multiscreenjs/) to make transitions,
So all my pages are in the same HTML doc

I'd like to make things appear when I load a page.
Document / windows ready can't work. And I don't think it's a viewport scrolling stuff that will fix the problem, because all my pages are 100% fixed height.

**How to say in jQuery : "When the user see X on screen, trigger X" ?**

thanks!

Comment: Sounds like you could do with something like Waypoints: http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/guides/getting-started/

Comment: Add code that you are trying to run.

Comment: Why you can't use document.ready?

Answer (score 0):

According to how multi-screen.js works there is a simple solution - you can use :visible selector to get necessary object right after DOM loading. Let's say your X object called #welcome. So the check will be like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // your X object is on the screen
    var isVisible = $('#welcome:visible').length > 0;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

JQuery offers several ways to check when an element is available, such as:

[.ready()](https://api.jquery.com/ready/)

> The .ready() method offers a way to run JavaScript code as soon as the
>   page's Document Object Model (DOM) becomes safe to manipulate.

```
$( "img" ).ready( handler )
```

and

[.load()](https://api.jquery.com/load-event/)

> The load event is sent to an element when it and all sub-elements
>   have been completely loaded. This event can be sent to any element
>   associated with a URL: images, scripts, frames, iframes, and the
>   window object.

```
$( "#book" ).load(function() {
  // Handler for .load() called.
});
```